# DB2 LUW-Json_Table function Syntax errors

Tags: db2-luw

I am trying to Insert array of Json data into a temporary table in DB2. I came to know that I can achieve this using Json_Table function. I found 2 links for this function with different syntax.

Can somebody help understand the difference between them?

1. https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0070414.html?pos=2
2. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.json.doc/doc/r0070289.html

As per my use-case i find link 1 is suitable, so i tried that example in **DB2 LUW V11.1/V11.5** Environment I am getting Syntax errors saying JSON_Table is Invalid. Is the syntax in Link 1 not supported in **DB2 LUW V11.1/V11.5**? Am I missing anything here?

I just took sample code as it is from Link 1 (https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0070414.html?pos=2) as shown below

```
SELECT U."id", U."first name", U."last name", U."phone number"
FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE E
JSON_TABLE(E.jsondoc, 'strict $'
           COLUMNS( "id" INTEGER,
                    "firstname"  VARCHAR(20),
                    "lastname"   VARCHAR(20),
                    "phoneno"    VARCHAR(20))
                    ERROR ON ERROR) AS U
```

I am getting Marker errors like "Multiple markers at this line

- DB2 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows: "<table_expr>" was expected to form a complete scope.
- DB2 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows: "U."id", U."first name", U."last name", U."phone number"
  FROM JSON_EMP E
  JSON_TABLE(E.EMP_DATA, 'strict $'
  COLUMNS( "id..."

When i tried to execute the above query I am getting Error as "‪An‬‎ ‪unexpected‬‎ ‪token‬‎ ‪‬‎"‪E"‬‎ ‪was‬‎ ‪found‬‎ ‪following‬‎ ‪‬‎"‪er"‬‎ ‪
‬‎ ‪ FROM‬‎ ‪JSON_EMP‬‎"‪.  Expected tokens may include:  "EXCEPT‬‎"‪.. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.19.56"

I tried to prefix JSON_TABLE with schema sysibm, but still no luck. I got same errors.

Comment: What Db2 version and platform are you on? What statement is causing the error?

Comment: Please post the exact code you tried, in your question. Links can die, and then the question would be meaningless without full context, not to mention proof that you copied and pasted successfully, didn't transcribe with a typo, etc. ;-) Please also include the full error received, as that one looks like it might've been abridged.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just added additional information in the description with the errors I am getting..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a number of errors in this example from documentation:
-- no comma before `JSON_TABLE`
-- contradictions in column names between `COLUMN` clause and `SELECT` list

Below is a working example:

```
/*
WITH EMPLOYEE_TABLE (jsondoc) AS 
(
VALUES 
'
{
  "id" : 901,
  "firstname" : "John",
  "lastname"  : "Doe",
  "phoneno"   : "555-3762"
}
'
)
*/
SELECT U."id", U."firstname", U."lastname", U."phoneno"
FROM 
  EMPLOYEE_TABLE E
, JSON_TABLE
(
  E.jsondoc, 'strict $' COLUMNS
  ( 
    "id" INTEGER
  , "firstname"  VARCHAR(20)
  , "lastname"   VARCHAR(20)
  , "phoneno"    VARCHAR(20)
  ) ERROR ON ERROR
) AS U;
```